# How to read a loop for reading each elements in each rows in a text file

Tags: python, for-loop, readline

I have a text file contain many rows and columns. I want to write a loop which goes in each row and pick up some of the row's element and calculate a formula and then goes to the next row. Do this for all lines (rows) in the file. I want to know how to specify each element in this file and how to call each element with the number of it's row and column. And finally how to write such loop.

So if I have a text file like below:

- 1 2 3 4 5
- 6 7 8 9 10
- 11 12 13 14 15

What I want to do is a loop which goes at first in first rows and pick two elements of that in second and third columns which are 2 and 3 here, do an operation, and then goes to next row and repeat this.

Comment: Please add some reproducible examples in your code block.

Answer (score 0):

You can create list with the lines as its elements.

```
with open(keyword_file) as f_in:
  lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f_in]
```

Then you can perform operations on each line's elements,

```
for line in lines:
  second_col_elem = line.split(' ')[1]
  third_col_elem = line.split(' ')[2]
  # do operation with above variables
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. With this I will call a whole column. But what I need is a loop to goes in each row at first and then read a third element and do operation and then goes to next row.

Comment: I have eddited the question, so show you exactly what I need to do.